# Map -1, 0, 1 to 1000, 1500, 2000

Tags: python, algorithm, pygame

This is my first time making an algorithm for any of my projects.
I have an Xbox controller I will be using in a Python script using Pygame to read the output from the controller. Pygame outputs 0 when centered, -1 when full left, and 1 when full right.
For my application I need to translate this to values between 1000 and 2000 where 1000 is -1, 1500 is 0, and 2000 is 1. 
Not asking necessarily for an answer, just some help with how to go about making an algorithm for myself.

Comment: Something wrong with the obvious `1500 + 500 * n`?

Answer (score 3):

If these are the only values possible, then you can create a dict to map Pygame outputs to your values.

```
positionMap = {-1:1000,0:1500,1:2000}
newVal = positionMap[oldVal]
```

But, if intermediate values are also possible then use this equation:

```
newVal = oldVal*500 + 1500
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do what you're asking.  The simplest way is a linear mapping using the two point form of a line.  You probably learned this in algebra but you might have forgotten it so here's a refresher:  http://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/line-equation-2points.html.

In your case, the x values are what you're given (-1 .. 1) and the y values are what you want (1000..2000).

Of course if you'd like to change the feel of the controller, you might choose not to use a linear function.  You might want something that slows down as you approach the limits of the controller for example.

Answer (score 1):

Your function can be of the form `f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c`. Put your transformations in a system and solve it:

```
a(-1)^2 + b(-1) + c = 1000
a*0^2 + b*0 + c = 1500
a*1^2 + b*1 + c = 2000

a - b + c = 1000
        c = 1500
a + b + c = 2000

a - b = -500
a + b = 500
=> 2a = 0 => a = 0
=> b = 500
```

So you can use the function `f(x) = 500x + 1500`.

```
f(-1) = 1000
f(0) = 1500
f(1) = 2000
f(0.3) = 1650
```

Comment: Why use quadratics to derive a linear equation?

Comment: The function assumed should not be a quadratic equation coz then one to one relation will not be maintained.

Comment: True, for this particular mapping there is no need to use a quadratic. I thought I'd be more general by suggesting something that also works for other mappings. It works in this case as well with little extra work.

Answer (score 0):

```
def mapInput(value):
    minInput = -1
    maxInput = 1
    minOutput = 1000
    maxOutput = 2000
    return (value - minInput)*(maxOutput-minOutput)/(maxInput-minInput) + minOutput
```

If those values are never going to change, then you could save a few processor cycles and just do:

```
def mapInput(value):
    return value * 500 + 1500
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to Python too, then might like to use an if/elif/else statement as that might be more readable for you:

```
if in_value == -1:
    out_value = 1000
elif in_value == 0:
    out_value = 1500
else:
    out_value = 2000
```

The code could be wrapped in a function or used in-line.